# How to save user response when feedback Intent gets triggered

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

In alexa skill when user response does not match with any utterance or any set value for custom slot then Amazon.FallbackIntent gets triggered .... I want to save that user response in in session attributes how can i do that explain by using python ask SDK. . .

I tried to capture that user response with input_transcript bt is not working....

Answer (score 0):

An Alexa Skill is not getting a transcript. The Fallback Intent is not different here when looking from an individual invocation as the Skill SDK is doing it.

But in the console it helps you with aggregated data:

> You can access aggregated and anonymized utterances with the Intent Request History API or the Intent History page in the developer console. This gives you a view into how users interact with your skill. You can view the utterances and the intents that Alexa triggered.

See https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/standard-built-in-intents.html#amazonfallbackintent-and-intent-request-history for more information

Comment: I got this.... But actually i want to use that user response in my code to post that user response on API so this will be not right solution for me....

Comment: For custom intent we create slot and fetch that slot value by using get_slot_value likewise when user response does not match with any intent slots value FallbackIntent gets triggered when it triggers I want to save that user response in handle function of FallbackIntent what can i do? Please guide me....

Comment: ok, misunderstood - I thought you where coming from matching custom slot with not defined value, when amazon matches the example phrase and so knows which part of the phrase is just for the slot, so they provide you even the STT part of that, because a single word(s) are not that privacy invasive then a whole phrase - but that only works if FallbackIntent is not active - I need to check, what we get in the JSON, when Fallback intercept this.